# Create Excel file in vbscript generates a corrupted file

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, datasheet

I have the following code in a vbscript:

```
    Set ExcelObject=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelObject.visible=False
    ExcelObject.WorkBooks.Add
    ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).value="1"
    ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(1,2).value="2"
    ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(1,3).value="3"
    ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(1,4).value="4"
    ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(2,1).value="5"
    ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(2,2).value="6"
    ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(2,3).value="7" 
    ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(2,4).value="Y"

    For x=0 to testData.Count-1
        ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(x+3,1).value=testData(x)
        ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(x+3,2).value="Constant"
        ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(x+3,4).value="Y"
    Next

    ExcelObject.Activeworkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Name"
    ExcelObject.Activeworkbook.SaveAs(path+"Data.xls")
    ExcelObject.Quit()
    Set ExcelObject=Nothing
```

Although, once I open this spreadsheet with Excel I get the following error:
***The file format and extension of "Data.xls" don't match. The file could be correupted or unsafe***...

Also, I cannot import this datasheet from UFT HP. I believe it might be because of this issue with how Excel file is being generated.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: save it as an xlsx.

Comment: I specifically need it to be xls as QTP ( now HP-UFT) requires it to be xls

Comment: then use the filetype parameter of the saveas command. Hint: don't include the .xls extension. Excel will put the correct one there if you get the code right.

Comment: I'm not sure how complex the file to save is. You may need to add `ExcelObject.DisplayAlerts = False` before saving to avoid confirmations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to SaveAs with *FileFormat* of **xlExcel8** . xlExcel8 is the equivalent of 56 (since VB-Script doesn't have the xlExcel8 reference).

```
ExcelObject.Activeworkbook.SaveAs(path+"Data", 56)
```

Don't add the extension. Excel will add the correct one according to the file type parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure how complex the file to save is. You may need to add `ExcelObject.DisplayAlerts = False` before saving to avoid confirmations.